# Count the number of intersections of line segments whose endpoints are located on a circle?

Tags: java, algorithm

---

> The input is an array of 2n integers which defines line segments by saying how the points located on a circle are paired
>   and connected. (Each point has its own pair that's connected to it.)
>
> Array `[2,3,0,1]` reads:
>
> Point 0 is connected to point 2
>  Point 1 is connected to point 3
>   
>  Point 2 is connected to point 0
>  Point 3 is connected to
>   point 1
>
> Meaning we have line segments (0,2) and (1,3).
>
> The points are located on a circle, in the same order that they are
>   located in the array. (Their exact coordinates are irrelevant.)
>
> Here is the picture of my array example. (1 intersection occured.)
>
> [image]
>
> The output is the number of intersections. (Number of points where 2 line segments touch.)
>
> What would be the best (fastest) way to calculate this?

What I've tried:

```
public static int count(int[] world) {
    int i = 0;
    int intersections = 0;
    int endpoint = 0;

    // run trought all points in order, find their pairs and check if the line they make is intersected
    while (i < world.length - 1) {

        if (world[i] == i+1) { // if 2 neighbouring points are connected, there are no intersections with the line they make
            i++;
        } else if (world[i] > i) { // don't need to check previously checked pairs
            endpoint = world[i];

                // check if any intersections with the line L(i,world[i]):
                // This goes through all points that are located before the endpoint of the line defined by point i and its pair world[i]
                // And checks if their pair is located after the endpoint, which means that the line they make intersects the line L(i,world[i])
                for (int j = i+1; j < endpoint; j++) {
                    if (world[j] > endpoint) {
                        intersections++;
                    }
            }
        } 
        i++;
    }

    return intersections;
}
```

Thanks to [saby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017527/count-the-number-of-intersections-of-line-segments-whose-endpoints-are-located-o/43017875#43017875)s answer, I also coded this:

```
    public static int countIntersections(int[] world) {
    int intersections = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < world.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (!C(i,world[i],i-j,world[i-j])) {
                intersections++;
            }
        }
    }

    return intersections;
}

public static boolean C(int a, int b, int x, int y) {
    return ((a <= x && b <= x) || (a >= x && b <= y) || (a >= x && b >= x));
}
```

Which gives the same results as my initial code meaning they both work! But my initial code is faster than this one.

I'll be accepting his answer since both codes work and optimization questions are better suited for [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observation**: Given two segments `L1: [a, b]` and `L2: [x, y]`, they **DONT** intersect if and only if `(a < x && b > y) || (x < a && y > b)`.
Call this Condition `C(L1, l2)`.

**Outline of Algorithm**:

- Iterate over the line segments one by one
- Take first line segment L1
- Take segment line segment L2 and calculate Condition `C(L1, L2)`. If it is false add 1 to your intersection count.
- Take segment L3 and calculate `C(L3, L1)` and `C(L3, L2)`. Add the 1s accordingly.
- For segment Ln, you have to calculate `C(Ln, Ln-1)`, `C(Ln, Ln-2)`...
- Time Complexity: `O(n^2)`. `n` being the number of segments

Comment: +1, will try later. I think someone was passing by and downvoted both the question and this answer without a reason...

Comment: How odd! Yea do try, and give feedback. If you want to improve the time complexity, may be it can be done.

Comment: If your a,b,x,y are the numbers of ordering of the points in the array, then the condition C should be `(a <= x && b <= x) || (a >= x && b <= y) || (a >= x && b >= x)` . By using that and iterating through the line segments my code of your idea gives the same results as the code I proposed in the question. But for array length 18, my code solves it in 23.6 seconds while your algorithm solves it in 32.5 s.

Comment: Oh! I meant array**s**, not an array.This code is just a part of my short program that writes out all possible combinations of those arrays of some length and then solves them all. This is the total time when solving all possible, valid arrays of length 18. Not just one array. It's less than a second for both codes when handling one array, yes. Sorry for the confusion!